# agreed helping him v/s agreed to help him

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

Given the following sentence

> *When I arrived home I could not stop thinking about why I had agreed helping him.*

The correct way of writing it is

> *When I arrived home I could not stop thinking about why I had agreed **to help** him.*

Is the first sentence incorrect or carries a different meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "Agree" has to be followed with a preposition. Thus, the first is incorrect.

"Agree" is commonly followed by "on", "to" or "with". In your case, the second sentence is correct as "to" is used with demands or requests.

Comment: The preposition is commonly dropped in British English.

Comment: Which one? The use of *to*?

Answer (score 3):

The first sentence is incorrect.
You could change it to:

> Why I had agreed with helping him.

and it would have the same meaning.

Comment: Why is incorrect?

Comment: Please see edit

Comment: I hadn't thought on adding *with*, it makes more sense. Is it because *agree with* stands for a phrasal verb?

Comment: I usually try to think of it as: one agreed "with" someone;  or "to" something; or "about" something.  Native speakers rarely think in terms of parts of speech.